# Conditional independence property: intersection

Tags: conditional-probability, independence

why are statement  1 and statement  2 analogous for disjoint sets?
Statement 1 (Intersection): if $X \perp Y \mid Z$ and $X \perp Z \mid Y$ then $X \perp (Y,Z)$.

Statement 2: if $A \perp B \mid (C \cup D)$ and  $A \perp C \mid (B \cup D)$ then  $A \perp (B \cup C) \mid  D$

Statement 2 is used as condition for Pearl and Paz theorem of equivalence of Markov properties for undirected graphs.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).